# How can I sort the results of a map/reduce using Doctrine ODM

Tags: mongodb, sorting, symfony, doctrine-odm, odm

I'm having an issue trying to sort after a map reduce.  The collection has statistics (like scores) with users attached, so it's finding the highest score of the user.  That portion works, the sort is to then sort those results for a leaderboard.  I've put these functions into javascript variables and run them in the mongo console and a simple find().sort({'value.max.value':-1}) works fine on the resulting collection but I can't get it to work here.  (My results come back unordered).

```
$query->map('function() { 
    var x = { value : parseInt(this.value), _id : this._id, date : this.postDate };
    emit(this.user, { max : x }); 
}')
->reduce('function(key, vals) {
    var res = vals[0];
    for (var i=1; i<vals.length; i++) 
    {
        if(vals[i].max.value > res.max.value)
            res.max = vals[i].max;
    }
    return res;
}')
->sort('value.max.value', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `->map` or `->reduce` call, Doctrine internally switch the `"query mode"` from `"find"` mode to `"mapreduce"` mode.

So you are actually doing a [mapReduce MongoDB command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) as in the [MongoDB Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce)

This means that your `sort()` call is translated to a sort property in the mapReduce command, and so it sorts only the **input** documents.

To actually sort the **output** you have 2 options:

- Use the `out()` method in the query to output the results to a temporary Collection, then query the data from there with sort
- Sort the results in php

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Hopefully next time I dive into doctrine they have the aggregation framework supported.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` of a map-reduce is applied to the *input* documents (as fed to `map`), not the result.  If you want to sort the results of the map-reduce you'd need to output to a collection and then perform a sorted `find` query on that collection (as you've successfully tried).